# Error in geolocation js (site.init is undefined)

Tags: javascript, ajax, geolocation, ip, frontend

I currently have a problem,
I have a client who wants his site in Argentina to be seen only in Argentina and that users entering from another country are redirected to the official website in France, and that when the API query is made if you are inside Argentina, the geolocation script is not executed It should be noted that the only way,the api that I am using is ip api, I have to create it in js. Because the system we are using does not give us access to server. and additionally a cookie must be saved. So I did the following.

```
var site = {
    init: function() {

        this.setDisplayClass();
        this.global();
        this.search();
        this.newsletter();
        menu.init();
        minicart.amount(".cart-link .qty-items");
        minicart.create();
        minicart.hover();
        if ($('body').hasClass('home')) {
            banner.background('.main-banner-section .box-banner');
            banner.slide('.run-slick');
            shelf.slide('.featured-products-slider .shelf ul');
        }
        if ($('body').hasClass('grid-products')) {
            grid.init();
        }
        if ($('body').hasClass('producto')) {
            product.init();
            shelf.slide('#related-products .shelf ul');
        }
    },
}
```

AND

```
var geo ={
    init: function(){
        var isAr = localStorage.getItem("country");
        if((isAr == null) || (isAr == undefined)){
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://ip-api.com/json/?callback=?',
                async: false,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (response) {
                    var country = response.countryCode;
                    if(country !== "AR"){
                        window.location.replace("https://www.google.com.ar");
                    }else{
                        localStorage.setItem('country', country);
                        if($(".loading-hidden").length > 0){
                            $(".loading-hidden").each(function(){
                                if ($(this).attr('style') == 'visibility: hidden;') {
                                    console.log(1);
                                    site.init();
                                    $(this).removeAttr('style');
                                    if ($("#loading").length > 0) {
                                        $("#loading").remove();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }else{
            if ($(".loading-hidden").attr('style') == 'visibility: hidden;') {
                            site.init();
                            $('.loading-hidden').removeAttr('style');
                            if ($("#loading").length > 0) {
                                $("#loading").remove();
                            }
                        }
        }

    }
}
```

AND

```
$(document).on('ready', function() {
});
site.init();

    $(window).bind("load", function() {

});
```

The error I get is that site.init is undefined.

Comment: Right now the error I get is that site.init is undefined.

Comment: What does the console log say? Is that traling comma in the site object a typo? Have you trimmed subsequent attributes?